# Heroku deployment with node.js and postgresql api not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express, heroku

I have been recently been working on a node.js api with a postgresql database that stores books.
When you go to the route /books it gives me the heroku application error page (here is the api https://node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com/books) and I followed this tutorial to make it https://www.taniarascia.com/node-express-postgresql-heroku/. It is driving me crazy and here is the error it gives when I do:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

```
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094893+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/index.js:12
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094902+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094903+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094904+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094904+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094905+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1498:34)
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094906+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:327:20)
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094906+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:933:8)
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094907+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:707:12) {
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094907+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
2021-03-15T04:04:21.094907+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-15T04:04:21.099759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/books" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=5ec4a052-1aed-4401-916d-1699f1fe9d3d fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=50ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-15T04:04:21.100313+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2021-03-15T04:04:21.100365+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.0.8 -> 7.6.3
2021-03-15T04:04:21.100444+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.6.3>
2021-03-15T04:04:21.100541+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.6.3` to update!
2021-03-15T04:04:21.100619+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2021-03-15T04:04:21.104741+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code 1
2021-03-15T04:04:21.104926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! path /app
2021-03-15T04:04:21.108208+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command failed
2021-03-15T04:04:21.108390+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command sh -c node index.js
2021-03-15T04:04:21.353877+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-15T04:04:21.354099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-15T04:04:21.354257+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-15T04_04_21_109Z-debug.log
2021-03-15T04:04:21.413929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-15T04:04:21.490613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-03-15T04:04:21.495328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-15T04:04:24.629509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-15T04:04:27.698683+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-15T04:04:27.698698+00:00 app[web.1]: > working-rest-api@1.0.0 start
2021-03-15T04:04:27.698698+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-15T04:04:27.698698+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-15T04:04:28.035756+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening
2021-03-15T04:04:28.553149+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332623+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/index.js:12
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332639+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332640+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332641+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332641+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332642+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1498:34)
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332643+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:327:20)
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332643+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:933:8)
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332643+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:707:12) {
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332644+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
2021-03-15T04:04:29.332644+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-15T04:04:29.340112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/books" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=8af9f82c-42c9-4399-9de3-ed80f7dee15a fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=74ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-15T04:04:29.343368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2021-03-15T04:04:29.343566+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.0.8 -> 7.6.3
2021-03-15T04:04:29.343688+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.6.3>
2021-03-15T04:04:29.343859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.6.3` to update!
2021-03-15T04:04:29.344058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2021-03-15T04:04:29.348863+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code 1
2021-03-15T04:04:29.349087+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! path /app
2021-03-15T04:04:29.352585+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command failed
2021-03-15T04:04:29.352766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command sh -c node index.js
2021-03-15T04:04:29.364318+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-15T04:04:29.364464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-15T04:04:29.364515+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-15T04_04_29_354Z-debug.log
2021-03-15T04:04:29.443525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-15T04:04:29.510747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I can add you on heroku if you have a idea
Here is my code on github https://github.com/PugmanD/gticlicker-api-and-book-api/tree/main

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is definitely something to do with the Certificate for HTTPS. Most likely when you're connecting to the Postgresql.


https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs?singlepage=true#provision-a-database

Could you share your code in a repo for us to take a look?

Comment: Ok I will add the link right now

Comment: Have you found anything in the code?

Comment: I will take a look in a while, =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying with the uploaded repo. I've confirmed the error lies at the following place

`config.js`

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
    ssl: isProduction, // The problem is this setting
});
```

Update your `config.js` to following

```
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
```

node-postgres did show how to setup the SSL in their documentation
https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl

The problem why u faced this is most likely that the node-postgres couldn't find your SSL cert, hence the error.

This is the heroku link that I've make it working, I will remove the project in a few days. Feel free to try it.
https://test-postgresl.herokuapp.com/books

Comment: I will apply that to my api to see if it will work when I get home from work I was having a similar error before because my env variables were not correct for the heroku posgresql

Comment: Just let me know if you have any further question here. Do help to accept the answer if it works =D

Comment: Alright thanks. I would say I am a pretty good javascript developer but when it comes to node js I am noob

Comment: Dont worry, it happens, and this is just some configuration issue. Happens to everyone all the time. Have fun!

Comment: Ok it worked on the books api but not on the GTI clicker api

Comment: Would you mind looking at my gti clicker api code because it is not working

Comment: I can invite you to the heroku project if needed

Comment: Did you update the `config.js` in GTI clicker API?

Comment: Never mind I had to init the database through heroku so now it works